# How can I write out an element from a list based on the index of an another element from an another list?

Tags: prolog

I am new to prolog and I don't really know how to solve this problem. I have a list which contains 7 numbers , I was able to get the Max and the Min of these numbers , but after that I have to write out an element from an another list with the same index of min and max of the first list .

```
start :- writeln('Write in seven numbers then type end.'),
            fill(L),
            lght(L,Sm),
            write(Sm),
            writeln(L),
    avg(L,Arvg),
    writeln('Avg of list:'),
    write(Arvg),
            min(L,Min),write('a minimum:'),write(Min),
            max(L,Max),write('a maximum:'),write(Max)
            ffile(F).

min([F|T],Min):-min(T,Min,F).
min([F|T],Min,Act):- number(F),F < Act, Newact is F, min(T,Min,Newact).
min([_|T],Min,Act):- min(T,Min,Act).
min([],Min,Min).
max([F|T],Max):-max(T,Max,F).
max([F|T],Max,Act):- number(F),F > Act, Newact is F, max(T,Max,Newact).
max([_|T],Max,Act):- max(T,Max,Act).
max([],Max,Max).
```

So I don't really have a clue how to match the min and max to a day for example from an another list.
P.S My code may contains non english words because I did not write it it full english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One step to answer your question will be to modify your predicates that find the minimum and maximum of a list by returning also the index. For example, modifying your code as:

```
minimum([Head| Tail], Minimum, Index) :-
    minimum(Tail, Head, Minimum, 2, 1, Index).

minimum([], Minimum, Minimum, _, Index, Index).
minimum([Head| Tail], Minimum0, Minimum, Position, Index0, Index) :-
    NextPosition is Position + 1,
    (   Head @< Minimum0 ->
        minimum(Tail,     Head, Minimum, NextPosition, Position, Index)
    ;   minimum(Tail, Minimum0, Minimum, NextPosition,   Index0, Index)
    ).
```

I used term comparison instead of arithmetic comparison to make the predicate more general. Sample calls:

```
| ?- minimum([7,3,4,5,1], M, I).
M = 1, I = 5
yes

| ?- minimum([7,3,1,4,5], M, I).
M = 1, I = 3
yes

| ?- minimum([1,7,3,4,5], M, I).
M = I, I = 1
yes
```

Can you proceed from here and update your answer with your efforts?

Answer (score 1):

You could take the following approach:

- make a list key-value pairs where the original value is the key and the index is the value;
- sort by the key (the original value);
- the first and the last *values* are now the indices of the min and the max, respectively;
- use the two indices and `nth1/3` to get the elements you need from the other list.

But do you really need the indices? If you only thought you need them because you'd like to get the elements from the other list, consider, instead:

- make a list of key-value pairs where the key is the elements from the first list and the value is the corresponding element from the second list;
- sort by key, get the first and the last value.

Like this:

```
keys_vals_min_max(Keys, Values, Min, Max) :-
    pairs_keys_values(Pairs, Keys, Values),
    keysort(Pairs, [_-Min|Rest]),
    last(Rest, _-Max).
```

With this I get:

```
?- keys_vals_min_max([2,7,1,3,5,4,6], [a,b,c,d,e,f,g], Min, Max).
Min = c,
Max = b.
```

Easy, right?

(Note: `keysort/2` does not remove duplicates and is stable.)

Please don't do this crap where you force the user to enter numbers one by one. This is ridiculous. If you need a list of 7 numbers, just type: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`. If you need the average of the numbers in a list, define a predicate called `list_average/2` and let the user query it like this:

```
?- list_average([1,2,3,4], Average).
Average = 2.5.
```

If you think you need state, don't worry too much about it. On the top level, you can start by writing down your input, then just hit the "up" button to get the previous query, and keep on adding stuff at the end of it. For example:

```
?- L = [1,2,3].
L = [1, 2, 3].

?- L = [1,2,3], length(L, N).
L = [1, 2, 3],
N = 3.

?- L = [1,2,3], length(L, N), sumlist(L, Sum).
L = [1, 2, 3],
N = 3,
Sum = 6.

?- L = [1,2,3], length(L, N), sumlist(L, Sum), Average is Sum / N.
L = [1, 2, 3],
N = 3,
Sum = 6,
Average = 2.
```

What if you want different input? Just hit the "up" button yet again and change the `L`:

```
?- L = [1,42], length(L, N), sumlist(L, Sum), Average is Sum / N.
L = [1, 42],
N = 2,
Sum = 43,
Average = 21.5.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , I changed up the input method , now it asks the user for a number to create a fix size list and then typing in the elements, I know it is kinda bad , but the sad reality is that my school makes me do things like this :(

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answers!

I was able to finish my task by writing a code that searches for the Index of the Min and Max in the first list and then matching the index numbers with the other list .

```
index([Element|_], Element, 0).
index([_|Tail], Element, Index):-
   index(Tail, Element, Index1),
   Index is Index1+1.
```

I used this code for searching for the indexes

```
match([Elem|_],Num,Num,Elem) :-
   !.
match([_|Tail],Num,Count,MatchedNumber) :-
   Count < Num,
   Count1 is Count+1,
   match(Tail,Num,Count1,MatchedNumber).
```

And then this code to match the index number with the other List's